# Face Detection (Emgu CV)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, opencv, emgucv

I writing app for face Detection using Emgu CV.

It is WPF app.

Here is code for my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfFaceDetectionTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Image Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" />
</Grid>
```

and code for my xaml.cs

```
   using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WpfFaceDetectionTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        private Capture capture;
        private HaarCascade haarCascade;
        DispatcherTimer timer;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            capture = new Capture();
            haarCascade = new HaarCascade("C:\\Users\\nemes\\Desktop\\WpfFaceDetectionTest\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
            timer.Start();
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image<Bgr,Byte> currentFrame = capture.QueryFrame();

            if (currentFrame != null)
            {
                Image<Gray, Byte> grayFrame = currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

                var detectedFaces = grayFrame.DetectHaarCascade(haarCascade)[0];

                foreach (var face in detectedFaces)
                    currentFrame.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(0, double.MaxValue, 0), 3);

                image1.Source = ToBitmapSource(currentFrame);
            }

        }

        [DllImport("gdi32")]
        private static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

        public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(IImage image)
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Bitmap source = image.Bitmap)
            {
                IntPtr ptr = source.GetHbitmap(); //obtain the Hbitmap

                BitmapSource bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                    ptr,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    Int32Rect.Empty,
                    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

                DeleteObject(ptr); //release the HBitmap
                return bs;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the videostream from web camera breaks.

How can I fix this issue?

Thank's for help

Comment: You may want to also list your OS specs and hardware model of your camera. My company has experienced issues with video streams and certain drivers (that we're still working on a fix for). Someone may be able to help identify if that's the case for you.

Comment: Windows 10. HP HD Webcam @RyanCarlisle

Comment: replace `image1.Source = ToBitmapSource(currentFrame);` to this `image1.Source = currentFrame.ToBitmap();`

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' WpfFaceDetectionTest @MD.NazmulKibria